# Filter objects in array in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, lodash

I have an array of objects within arrays from selected tags

```
const posts = 
[{note: 'something..', title: 'something..',
tags: [{title: 'First tag', key: '123'}, {title: 'Second tag', key: 'ABC'}]}, 
{note: 'another post..', title: 'another post..', 
tags: [{title: 'third tag', key: '098'}, {title: 'forth tag', key: 'ZYX'}, {title: 'fifth tag', key: '1A9'}]}]
```

And I have an array with keys

```
const keys = ['123', 'ABC', '098', 'ZYX', '1A9']
```

I want to return the filtered posts. So I tried to `.map` and `.filter` over these posts to try to match with the keys, but it doesn't work for me.

First I need to map over posts to get to the tags and map over these and then I need to map over the array with keys to match them with the keys in the array of tags and return the post that contains the matched tag.

Comment: Post the code you tried

Comment: And what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter by checking the tags with the keys.

```js
var posts = [{ note: 'something..', title: 'something..', tags: [{ title: 'First tag', key: '123' }, { title: 'Second tag', key: 'ABC' }] }, { note: 'another post..', title: 'another post..', tags: [{ title: 'third tag', key: '098' }, { title: 'forth tag', key: 'ZYX' }, { title: 'fifth tag', key: '1A9' }] }],
    keys = ['123'], //, 'ABC', '098', 'ZYX', '1A9'],
    result = posts.filter(({ tags }) => tags.some(({ key }) => keys.includes(key)));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
const posts = [{note: 'something..', title: 'something..', tags: [{title: 'First tag', key: '123'}, {title: 'Second tag', key: 'ABC'}]}, {note: 'another post..', title: 'another post..', tags: [{title: 'third tag', key: '098'}, {title: 'forth tag', key: 'ZYX'}, {title: 'fifth tag', key: '1A9'}]}]


const keys = ['123', 'ABC', '098', 'ZYX', '1A9']

const filtered = posts.filter(post =>
   post.tags.some( tag => 
      keys.includes( tag.key )
     )
   )
```

Comment: Thanks! i forgot the 'some'